# rtorrent - How to keep information for reseeding later

Tags: rtorrent

I have box with internet connection and limited space. I have also much more space offline.

I download fime files with **rTorrent**, share them for some time, then move them to offline space to be able download more files.

**Sometimes later somebody asks me to share those files again, so I would like to put them back to sharing, but I do not know how.**

---

Details

1. **I download magnet URL** ( magnet:?xt=urn:btih:12345.... )
2. cd ~/torrents
3. echo "d10:magnet-uri${#1}:${1}e" > "meta-${BASH_REMATCH[1]}.torrent" # create meta-12345...torrent
4. rtorrent downloads 12345...meta to ~/torrents/Downloads
5. rtorrent downloads and share ~/torrents/Downloads/some_dir/some_files*
6. I stop rTorrent, **move** all Downloads/some_dir **to offline storage**, free the space
7. much later somebody asks to share some_dir again (as no seeded is active)
8. I copy some_dir from offline to the box ~/torrents/Download/some_dir
9. **What now?** How to say rtorrent, to share it again under the original magnet?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it will work, but try add the torrent again, exit rtorrent, move the completed file over the new created place holder which crated by the new torrent, and start rtorrent again, next forcing hash check (`Ctrl-r`) which will initiate a hash check of the torrent, and if you have the file in the same place, after the hash checking the file will marked as completed and will start seeding.

Answer (score 1):

`rtorrent` has the posibility to "watch" directories for torrent-files. As soon as a new file arrives it loads them again (shares them again). I assume the torrent-file contain information for at least one tracker.

I did not test this by myself, but I think this page is a good starting point for solving your problem.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/RTorrent